# How to replace image stored in cache?

Tags: ios, swift, caching, firebase, firebase-storage

On my application I'm caching the images of the users to use less data when scrolling through a `tableView`. I'm caching the profile pictures as they are being loaded, however, when I change the profile picture of the current user, the cached image on the posts created by the current user doesn't change.

The way to works is the following:

- I retrieve the posts that all users have wrote and display them on a `tableView`
- The posts contain the user ID
- I use the user ID to obtain the user's username, name, and profile picture
- When retrieving the images into the `tableView`, I cache them
- When a user changes the profile picture, the image displayed on the `tableView` is the same as the previous image instead of the new one

So we go back to my question, how can I replace the image cached whenever there's a change in the user profile picture?

Here's my caching extension if it helps for anything:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseStorage

let imageCache = NSCache<AnyObject, AnyObject>()

var databaseRef: FIRDatabaseReference! {
    return FIRDatabase.database().reference()
}

var storageRef: FIRStorage! {
    return FIRStorage.storage()
}

extension UIImageView{

    func loadProfilePictureWithCash(postUser: String){

        let userRef = databaseRef.child("users/\(postUser)")

        userRef.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

            let user = User(snapshot: snapshot)

            let imageURL = user.photoURL!

            // check cache for image first
            if let cachedImage = imageCache.object(forKey: imageURL as AnyObject){
                self.image = cachedImage as? UIImage
                return
            }
            else{
                storageRef.reference(forURL: imageURL).data(withMaxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024, completion: { (imageData, error) in
                    if error == nil {

                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            if let data = imageData{

                                if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data) {
                                    imageCache.setObject(downloadedImage, forKey: imageURL as AnyObject)

                                    self.image = downloadedImage
                                }

                            }
                        }

                    }
                    else{
                        print(error?.localizedDescription as Any)
                    }
                })
            }

        }) { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Is `user.photoURL` being updated when the user uploads a new profile photo? Presumably you would need to update that member and then call `tableView.reloadData()` in order to refresh the UI with the updated image.

Comment: @MichaelFourre you know what, it is updating, but I have the profile picture URL set as the same. For example: https://firebase.com/user/profilePic/uid.jpg

and when updating the picture, the URL is the same.

What do you recommend me to do? Add a autoID generator for each profile photo the user uploads so the URL is different?

Comment: Then why not just manually update the image in cache when the user confirms their new profile picture? So `imageCache.set(newProfilePicture, forKey: user.photoURL!)` after the user has submitted the new profile photo.

Comment: @MichaelFourre Wouldn't that just update the image locally? What if other users are using the application at the same time the profile picture update happened? It wouldn't update for them, would it?

Comment: Definitely. Based on your question, you hadn't made it clear that you are concerned about updating that profile photo for other people as well. If that is the concern, then the easiest method (in my opinion) is to assign a unique identifying value to each profile photo and use that as the key when storing in cache. In your event, replacing one image with another image at the same URL provides no uniqueness on the client side. Either assign an ID to profile photos or upload the new profile photo at a unique new URL. Other solutions are likely to be messy and not innately apparent.

Comment: @MichaelFourre will be adding an ID to the URL to make them unique. Thanks.